# Can the rules on book advice be clarified in the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, recommendations, faq-contents

According to a discussion I had in the comments on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766136/what-should-i-learn-to-be-a-better-enterprise-worthy-software-developer#comment15625113_11766136), it seems that asking for a list of book recommendations is verboten on Programmers.

The site's FAQ gives me the opposite impression.  To me, as long as it's asking for recommendations a topic like the ones listed in the bullet list under "What kind of questions can I ask here?":

- algorithm and data structure concepts
- design patterns
- developer testing
- development methodologies
- freelancing and business concerns
- quality assurance
- software architecture
- software engineering
- software licensing

then it seems like that should be fine.  It seems to me like a constructive type of question, and doesn't seem to violate the guidelines on what counts as a "constructive subjective question". A good book recommendation would include some explanation for why it's being recommended, which would make it right in line with the list of 6 characteristics to look for in the kinds of answers that a constructive subjective question should inspire.

Apparently what's supposed to tell me that the opposite is true is the sentence, "Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."  That doesn't communicate it to me, either.  To me, asking about books related to a certain topic doesn't seem open-ended at all.  After all, there's a defined topic being asked about.

---

So I'd like to suggest that the FAQ be clarified a bit.  Perhaps an extra bullet point could be added to the list of things a question should not be about up at the top of the page?  Perhaps something along the lines of

- Recommendations for learning resources, technologies, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Book suggestions are adequately outlined between the **What about suggestive questions** and the **What kind of questions should I not ask here** sections. The 6 suggested guidelines:

> inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”.

Book recommendations don't fit this based on experience of what answers they generate.

> tend to have long, not short, answers.

Again book recommendations to to have very short "this book was good" type answers and worse link only answers.

> have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone.

Book recommendations are generally OK on this point.

> invite sharing experiences over opinions.

Book recommendations fail this point as it is mostly opinion based answers.

> insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references.

Book recommendations fail this as well answers reflect popular opinion not anything that could be cited.

> are more than just mindless social fun.

Book recommendations are OK here.

So 4 out of 6 of the guidelines are a no, furthermore there is [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) Stack Exchange blog post that further clarifies these guidelines, which is also linked in the FAQ. [More](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2003/41381) reading about book recommendations. There are [some ways](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/41381) to post book recommendations though.

Comment: The first two 'no's, though, are based on experience that Stack Exchange veterans have observed.  Like I said in my comment, a reasonable a priori assumption (at least to people like me) is that book recommendations would be 'yes'es on those two points.  Bringing the tally to 4 yes and 2 no.  Shouldn't the FAQ be or newcomers, and therefore not rely the assumption that someone reading it would have pre-existing knowledge of how these things have worked out in the past?

Comment: @SeanU if the rule was absolutely no books recommendations it would make sense to put it in the FAQ, but its more of a grey area that would be a long and complicated addition to the FAQ, and our FAQ is pretty long already.

Comment: So what's an example of a book recommendation that's okay, and an example of one that's not okay, and what's the difference?  Surely the guidelines can be explained in a way that makes sense to the intended reader and not just the author.

Comment: @SeanU See the [Meta FAQ entry for Book Recommendations](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1130). Basically if your question will produce a list of everyone's favourite book, its off topic, but if it will elicit the title of *the* book on a topic then its OK. The difference is the first doesn't have a single right answer, while the second does.

Comment: @SeanU [here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/3034/41381) are some examples, I added this link to my answer as well.

Comment: ChrisF's comment on the Meta FAQ entry is very succinct and clear.  I'm sure it could be made even more succinct for inclusion in the FAQ, rather than being left [hidden in a response to a Meta question on the FAQ](http://www.kafejo.com/iq/mensa/picsinfo.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think something should be in the FAQ explicitly stating that questions asking for broad recommendations are not allowed on this site.

I see many questions getting closed because they're asking for a broad recommendation, such as book topics, framework advice, shopping advice, etc.

Since they all get closed for being a broad recommendation, it makes more sense to explicitly state in the faq that broad recommendations are off-topic here, and not try to list every type of broad recommendation in its own bullet point.

Adding such a line would actually shorten our faq a bit too, which is always a good thing since its so long already.

> and it is **not about**...
>
> - general workplace issues, office politics, résumé help (check out The Workplace instead),
> - implementation issues or programming tools (ask on Stack Overflow instead),
> - **broad recommendations, such as what language/technology you should learn next, what book you should read, or what project you should do
>     next**
> - career advice, salary or compensation,
> - personal lifestyle, including relationships, and non-programming activities

Comment: Where's "including which technology is better"? I like the "broad recommendations" bullet, but "including which technology is better" is more of a "broad comparison" thing than a "broad recommendation".

Comment: @YannisRizos I had simply combined it in the first example: "what language/*technology* you should learn next", although you're right that it addresses "what should I learn next" and not "what is better". Perhaps that could be rephrased a bit, like "broad recommendations or comparisons, such as what language you should learn next, which technology is better, what book you should read, or what project you should do next"

Comment: Hm, I see them as different things, broad recommendations are "tell me what to use/read", broad comparisons are "foo vs bar", don't know how easy they are to combine. Perhaps two bullets instead of one?

Comment: @YannisRizos That would work. We could also just leave the "what technology is better" line in the off-topic list, since the majority of off-topic comparisons that get asked are which technology is better :)

Comment: Hm, now that's interesting, we should sit down, examine our closures, see what the actual percentages are (foo vs bar is probably the majority) and re-arrange our off topic list based on hard data.